Failed to get sandbox image
During the PieCloudDB Database installation process, when I used kubekey to set up Kubernetes, I encountered an issue where kubelet was not starting as expected. My container runtime is containerd. Upon inspecting the kubelet logs, I found an error:
failed to get sandbox image \"k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2\": failed to pull image \"k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2\" ....


After editing the /etc/containerd/config.toml configuration file to update the sandbox_image setting to the local harbor's pause image address. I resolved this issue.
replace sandbox_image = "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2"
to      sandbox_image = "mydomain.com/k8s/pause:3.7"

